# How to connect to wifi using simple wifi in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to connect to wifi using `simplewifi`. Currently, I have tried:

```
Wifi wifi = new Wifi();

// get list of access points
IEnumerable<AccessPoint> accessPoints = wifi.GetAccessPoints();

// for each access point from the list
foreach (AccessPoint ap in accessPoints)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ap: {0}\r\n", ap.Name);
    //check if SSID is desired
    if (ap.Name.StartsWith("z"))
    {
        //verify connection to desired SSID
        Console.WriteLine("connected: {0}, password needed: {1}, has profile: {2}\r\n", ap.Name, ap.IsConnected, ap.HasProfile);
        if (!ap.IsConnected)
        {
            //connect if not connected
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n{0}\r\n", ap.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect..\r\n");

            AuthRequest authRequest = new AuthRequest(ap);
            authRequest.Password = "123456789";
            var x=ap.Connect(authRequest);

        }
    }
}
```

[image: see the change in zshnu after I tried this code]

Here I am not able to pass the password if I have the password hardcoded like

```
var password="abc123"
```

How can I pass the password and connect?

Also, the connect method always returns `false`, even if I have to connect to a wifi with no password.

Comment: Include all the output from the program, make sure you are not connected to any network..

Comment: ap: zshnu connected: zshnu, password needed: False, has profile: True Interface: WiFi Auth algorithm: RSNA_PSK Cipher algorithm: CCMP BSS type: Infrastructure Connectable: False Reason to false: MSMSEC_CAPABILITY_PROFILE_AUTH Trying to connect..  this was the output i got

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `authRequest.Password = "yourpassword";`

before your `ap.connect(authRequest);`

Add in following `console.write()` from https://github.com/DigiExam/simplewifi

Place at the top of your file

```
using SimpleWifi;
```

Then in your function

```
// Wifi object
Wifi wifi = new Wifi();

// get list of access points
IEnumerable<AccessPoint> accessPoints = wifi.GetAccessPoints();

    // for each access point from list
foreach (AccessPoint ap in accessPoints){
    Console.WriteLine("ap: {0}\r\n", ap.Name);
    //check if SSID is desired
    if (ap.Name.StartsWith("ardrone_")){
        //verify connection to desired SSID
        Console.WriteLine("connected: {0}, password needed: {1}, has profile: {2}\r\n", ap.Name, ap.IsConnected, ap.HasProfile);
        if (!ap.IsConnected){
            //connect if not connected
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n{0}\r\n", ap.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect..\r\n");
            AuthRequest authRequest = new AuthRequest(ap);
            ap.Connect(authRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, its not connecting, even wifi without password not connecting

Comment: You might need to run your application in elevated mode. Also have you debugged the code actually making sure it will execute the connect? if (!ap.IsConnected), if there is an connection that will never execute..

Comment: I disconnected all internet and tried to connect, ispasswordvalid verification gives true, but while connecting it fails

Comment: You should update your question with you actually need help with, you asked for how to set the password for the connection and I answered that question and now you asking something different. If there is an error, provide the error etc..

Comment: if you try this code in a console app, and try to connect to a wifi without password, it wont connect ap.connect() will return false.

Comment: Can you copy paste the output from when you run the code I added to my answer

Comment: ap: zshnu

connected: zshnu, password needed: False, has profile: True


Interface: WiFi
Auth algorithm: RSNA_PSK
Cipher algorithm: CCMP
BSS type: Infrastructure
Connectable: False
Reason to false: MSMSEC_CAPABILITY_PROFILE_AUTH


Trying to connect..

Comment: and my os is w10

Comment: So.. Only one AP and its named *zshnu* and its already connected so you only try to connect to networks starting with *ardrone_* and only if not already connected.. Use a debugger, do step by step.. Look at the values and you will realize easier why connection is not working

Comment: startingwith I have changed to connect to zshnu

Comment: i did debug also, that's why i told its not connecting.

Comment: when i executed this code , in wifi list for that particular wifi cross mark is shown

Comment: Update the question with any changes/updates to code and reported results, error messages etc, impossible to help you otherwise. Don't put details of your findings in this comment field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148839/discussion-between-vishnuprasad-kv-and-stefane).

Answer (score 2):

Adding overwriteProfile set to "true" to parameters of the AccessPoint.Connect method solved the problem for me.

F# example:

```
open SimpleWifi

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let wifi = Wifi()
    let accessPoint = wifi.GetAccessPoints() 
                      |> Seq.find (fun (i:AccessPoint) -> i.Name = "Tpkl6" )

    let try1 = accessPoint.Connect( AuthRequest(accessPoint, Password="12345678"), true )
    let try2 = accessPoint.Connect( AuthRequest(accessPoint, Password="markvirchenko20"), true )

    printfn "%b\n%b" try1 try2
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

By the way, you asked about ispasswordvalid function in the comments:

> I disconnected all internet and tried to connect, ispasswordvalid verification gives true, but while connecting it fails

ispasswordvalid doesn't actually check if the password is correct i.e matching the one set on the wifi. It simply checks if the password has a valid structure, e.g at least 8 symbols length.